# Is the fixed phrase "belong WITH something" still in use?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

As I was reading a myth, I bumped into a sentence like

> The creature does not belong **with** mankind

I am not sure if it is still possible to use this expression. Has it not been replaced totally with **belong to**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's predicated on a misunderstanding. If I say *This child belongs with his family*, that doesn't mean his family "own" him - it means *that's where he should be*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, we wouldn't want to clear up any misunderstandings.

Comment: @deadrat:  But I *did* clear up the misunderstanding! Which I'd probably have posted as an answer rather than a comment if it had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Belong with*** has a different meaning to ***belong to***.

*The car belongs to John* means that John owns the car.

*The car belongs with John* means that John has temporary or permanent custody of the car, and that is where it should be. John **may** be the owner, but *belongs with* doesn't tell us who the owner is. It would be perfectly grammatical to say *The car is owned by Susan but belongs with John as he uses it in his business*.

One could also say *The car belongs with all the other cars in the car park*, meaning that is where the car ought to be.

Comment: Then how to distinguish between "you belong with me" and "you belong to me"?

Comment: @Technically no one *belongs to* anyone else, and hasn't done since slavery was abolished. But the expression is sort of used metaphorically by couples, usually endearingly.

Comment: My doubt came out when I saw both expressions in lyrics. I get it, now. Many thanks!